# FILE_SKIP_NEW_LINES for file() in PHP doesn't work (v4.4.9)

Tags: php, file

I recently switched over to my friends server, and had to edit some code in my files,
and noticed that FILE_SKIP_NEW_LINES doesn't seem to work for the file function.

When doing a var_dump on a variable I made with file(),
it gives me `"[key]" => "[value] "` (notice the space after [value]).
Was this flag not available in version 4.4.9, or what?

Unfortunately, it's just a web hotel, so he can't update the PHP version.

Comment: PHP 5 was released in 2004. That's 6 years ago. It is amazing that your friend's host is running anything that old.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), what you suspect is indeed true.

> Prior to PHP 5.0.0 the `flags` parameter only covered include_path and was enabled with 1

Comment: Oh, yeah... I see it now. Didn't see it the first time I looked through. So, what are my alternatives here?

Comment: @Nisto if at all possible, upgrade to PHP 5. PHP 4 is *dead*

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'll try asking him again to make sure. For now, I ended up making a foreach loop, to make the list I was trying to do originally.